# Non-Invocable error when use MethodInvoker

Tags: c#, invoke

I use this code :

```
 MethodInvoker TileLoadCompleteMethodInvoker = delegate()
{
    CleanStatusLabelTimer.Enabled = true;
    MemoryTextBox.Text = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0.00} MB of {1:0.00} MB", MainMapControl.Manager.MemoryCache.Size, MainMapControl.Manager.MemoryCache.Capacity);
};
try
{
    BeginInvoke(TileLoadCompleteMethodInvoker);
}
catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
{
    BLL.FunctionsClass.LogExceptions(ex.InnerException);
}
```

LogExceptions method is here :

```
    public class LogExceptions
{
public static void WriteLogException(Exception exMsg)
{
    string filePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\ExceptionLog.log";
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath, true))
    {
        file.WriteLine("-------------------Exception Begin----------------------");
        file.WriteLine(string.Format("Date: {0}, Time: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()));
        file.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception Message: {0}", exMsg.ToString()));
        file.WriteLine(string.Format("Source: {0}", exMsg.Source));
        file.WriteLine("-------------------Exception End----------------------");
        file.WriteLine();
    }
}
}
```

this method save exceptions in log file. but this error happend when call LogExceptions method;
**Non-invocable member 'IslamAtlas.BLL.FunctionsClass.LogExceptions' cannot be used like a method.**
how can i fix this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling class, not method!
Use this instead:

```
BLL.FunctionsClass.LogExceptions.WriteLogException(ex.InnerException);
```

More: you have another error here:

```
string.Format("Date: {0}, Time: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()
```

You call `String.Format` with two arguments but pass only one!

More and more: this line

```
string.Format("Exception Message: {0}", exMsg.ToString())
```

should be in my opinion

```
string.Format("Exception Message: {0}", exMsg.Message)
```

Comment: I use InnerException but not true and error happend. :D I fix string.format.

Comment: @1mohammadi.ir: do you see my and leppie answers? You **MUST** change your code with function name *WriteLogException*.

Answer (score 0):

You have call it like:

```
BLL.FunctionsClass.LogExceptions.WriteLogException(ex.InnerException);
```